# OnClick event is only getting the first dynamically created row/id

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a table where if X has a value, display X, otherwise, add a link which when clicked will display a textbox where user can input the value. I dynamically assign IDs/classes to the link and textboxes but when I run the application, each click on any link only seems to trigger the first row. I put in alerts to show what row is being clicked and I always get the first row. Looking at the browser DOM explorer, I can see that each row has its own unique ID. How do I get each OnClick event to grab the correct corresponding ID?

C#/Razor code:

```
 <td>
      <a href="#" class="unmapped" onclick="UnmappedClick()" id="@string.Format("tr{0}",i)">Unmapped</a>
      <input type ="submit" class="editAction hidden" value="@string.Format("tr{0}",i)" name="action:ChangeToEditSubAction" />
      <input type="hidden" name="@Html.Raw("EntityMapping.EMREntityID")" value="@Html.Raw(Model.DisplayResults[i].EMREntityID)" />
      <span class="@string.Format("tr{0}accountTxtBox",i) hidden">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EntityMapping.AssignedHOAccountID)</span> </td>
```

Javascript Function

```
 function UnmappedClick() {
    //$(".accountTxtBox").removeClass("hidden");
    //$(".unmapped").addClass("hidden");
    //$("#btnSave").removeAttr('disabled');
    //$(".editAction").click();
    //$(".editAction").val(null);

    alert($(".unmapped").attr('id'));
    var txtBox = $(".editAction").val();
    var actTextBox = "." + txtBox + "accountTxtBox";
    $(actTextBox).removeClass("hidden");
    alert(txtBox);

}
```

[DOM Explorer Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9o5A.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a parameter from your onclick event using the "this" keyword.

```
onclick="UnmappedClick(this.id)"

function UnmappedClick(id){
 //now you have the specific ID
}
```

or if necessary pass the whole control over

```
onclick="UnmappedClick(this)"
```

Comment: Thanks. Just did this. No luck :( still alerts "Undefined"

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$(this).attr('id') // use this
```

instead of

```
$(".unmapped").attr('id')
```

This will give you the current elements id when you click

Comment: I just did an alert on that and got "undefined".

Comment: Can you pass 'this' in the function call                                                                                    
         'onclick="UnmappedClick(this)"     '                                                                and try to get it in the function                                                                             
         'UnmappedClick(this){ } '

Comment: I tried to pass 'this' and got this error." The use of a keyword for an identifier is invalid"

Comment: Please try this,add at the onclick                                                                                                          
       ` UnmappedClick(this.id)`                                                                                   and                                                                                                                                 `function UnmappedClick(id){
   alert(id);                                                                                                           
   write down your custom logic//                 
} `

Comment: OMG That worked!! You're a champion! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/), using `$('.class')` will return a list all the elements with that class. When you use `$(".unmapped").attr('id')` you'll always get the value of the first element in the list, that's why you always get the first row.

The same will happen with `var txtBox = $(".editAction").val();`. With `$(actTextBox).removeClass("hidden");` you'll remove the class hidden from all the elements matched.

To get the id of an element you can use `onclick="unmapped(this)` or `onclick="unmapped(this.id)"` using the following code depending on the onclick attribute

```
function unmapped(element) {
    var id = $(element).attr('id')
    alert(id)
}

function unmapped(id) {
    alert(id)
}
```

You can check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3Lfzyhe3/) to see them in action.